# Changing only one of multiple named, nested routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

I have a template with multiple named, nested views:

template 1:

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

template 2:

```
<header></header>
<div ui-view="left"></div>
<div ui-view="canvas"></div>
<div ui-view="right"></div>
```

and I have the following config setup:

```
    .state("metricDashboard", {
        url: "/metric-dashboard",
        css: { href: "core/metric-dashboard/style.css" },
        views: {
            "": {
                templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/view.html",
                controller: 'MetricDashboard',
            },
            "left@metricDashboard": {
                templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/partials/left.html",
                controller: "MetricDashboardLeft",
            },
            "canvas@metricDashboard": {
                templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/partials/canvas.html",
                controller: "MetricDashboardCanvas"
            },
            "right@metricDashboard": {
                templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/partials/right.html",
                controller: "MetricDashboardRight"
            }
        }
    })
```

How would I go about changing an individual route? For example, If I wanted to change "left@metricDashboard", but leave the "canvas" and "right" routes alone. I cannot seem to find a syntax without creating a new state and explicitly declaring all the routes over again.

Comment: if it is a child state you don't have to declare all views just the ones that change

Comment: I thought I've tried that. Can you provide some syntax?

Comment: can you be more specific of what you want to achieve?

Comment: take a look at my answer, is that what you want?

Comment: I think that might be it. I'm doing some testing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm guessing you want to create another state that will change only one of the views not all of them.

Let's call it `left` and make it a child of `metricsDashboard`

```
.state("metricDashboard", {
    url: "/metric-dashboard",
    css: { href: "core/metric-dashboard/style.css" },
    views: {
        "": {
            templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/view.html",
            controller: 'MetricDashboard',
        },
        "left@metricDashboard": {
            templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/partials/left.html",
            controller: "MetricDashboardLeft",
        },
        "canvas@metricDashboard": {
            templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/partials/canvas.html",
            controller: "MetricDashboardCanvas"
        },
        "right@metricDashboard": {
            templateUrl: "core/metric-dashboard/partials/right.html",
            controller: "MetricDashboardRight"
        }
    }
})
.state("metricDashboard.left", {
    url: "left",
    views: {
        "left@metricDashboard" : {
            templateUrl: "some.html",
            controller: "AwesomeCtl",
            controllerAs: "awe"
        }
    }
})
```

Now when you enter that state only the left view will change the others will remain as defined in the parent state `metricDashboard`.

Comment: Alright. I did get this working. At first I thought it was not working, but I just had to add the `css: { href: "core/metric-dashboard/style.css" },` property in there since I am using css routing.